# GROUP BY with MAX on date

Tags: mysql, group-by, max

I have table with id, visit date and phone number.

```
        id    phone_number   visit_date
       2131   +7935345432    2020-03-17
       2135   +7935345432    2020-03-17
       3021   +4953433245    2020-02-21
       3078   +4953433245    2020-01-26
```

I need to receive id of row for last visit by each phone group. For example:

```
        id    phone_number   visit_date
       2131   +7935345432    2020-03-17
       3021   +4953433245    2020-02-21
```

I have a query:

```
    SELECT id, phone_number, MAX(visit_date) 
    FROM test
    GROUP BY phone_number;
```

But there is an error that id is nonaggregated column. Using a subquery goes that query gives multiple duplicated dates if they have the same value. Help me please

Comment: на Stack Overflow на русском вопросы принято задавать **только на русском языке**. Пожалуйста, переведите ваш вопрос на русский язык или воспользуйтесь Stack Overflow на английском.

Comment: Столбца phone_prim не существует

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    table1.*
FROM
    (SELECT 
        phone_number,
        MAX(visit_date) as lastDate
    FROM 
        test1
    GROUP BY phone_number) as lasts,
    (SELECT * FROM test1) as table1
WHERE
    lasts.lastDate = table1.visit_date
    AND
    lasts.phone_number = table1.phone_number;
```

Выводит id-шники 1, 2, 3

Comment: Не работает такой вариант(

Comment: @СергейСтепанович это работает. Нужно было просто phone_number выбрать

Comment: По-сути, нужно просто удалить id.

Comment: Так идея именно в том, чтобы получить эти id

Comment: @СергейСтепанович Хмм, дата посещения данной персоной может совпадать. Как тогда вы себе представляете таблицу?

Comment: "I need to receive id of row for last visit by each phone group" - их может быть несколько, вот, что я имею ввиду

Comment: @СергейСтепанович Сделал так, чтобы, если их несколько, выводились все